# Flatness of a morphism for an infinitesimal deformation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, flatness, deformation-theory

I am trying to learn about infinitesimal deformations and I am particularly looking at Example 1.2.2 (i) from the book *Deformations of Algebraic Schemes* by Edoardo Sernesi which states the following:

The quadric $Q\subseteq\mathbb{A}^{3}$ of equation $xy-t=0$ defines, via the
projection
$$\begin{array}{rccc}
    \pi: & \mathbb{A}^{3} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{A}^{1}  \\
            & (x,y,t)        & \longmapsto     &        t.
\end{array}$$
a flat family $Q\longrightarrow\mathbb{A}^{1}$. This means that we have the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Q @>{}>> \mathbb{A}^{3}\\
@VVV @VVV{\pi} \\
\mathrm{Spec}(k) @>{}>> \mathbb{A}^{1}
\end{CD}$$
where $\pi$ is flat and surjective, and $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ is connected.

**Question:** How to prove that $\pi$ is flat?

**Definition.** Let $f:X\longrightarrow S$ be a morphism of schemes. We say $f$ is flat at a point $x\in X$ if the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is flat over the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{S,f(x)}$. We say $f$ is flat if $f$ is flat at every point of $X$.

Going back to the Example, I have to $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathbb{A}^{3}$, then $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{3},\mathfrak{p}}\cong k[x,y,z]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{1},\pi(\mathfrak{p})}\cong k[w]_{\left<w-a\right>}$ for some $a\in k$. How prove $k[x,y,z]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is flat over $k[w]_{\left<w-a\right>}$?

**Question:** Do you have another idea how to prove that $\pi$ is a flat morphism?

Any hint to solve the doubt will be welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: A morphism of affine schemes $\varphi:\operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is flat iff the induced map $f:R\to A$ on global sections is flat. This will be covered in any introductory algebraic geometry book.

Comment: Torsion-free modules over PIDs are flat.